# Get value of a dynamic radio button with jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm pretty much a total jquery noob I'm afraid! I'm sure this is a very simple thing but I can't seem to work it out.

I'm trying to get the value of a dynamic, selected radio button.

HTML...

```
<div id="holder" class="">
<table id="qual-holder" class="table table-striped qual-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sector</th>
            <th>Qualification Title</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Confirm</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class="sector_qual">
        <td>OM207</td>
        <td>Diploma in Children and Young People's Workforce Level 3</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
            <input name="qualification" id="28" type="radio" value="28" class="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sector_qual">
        <td>OM207</td>
        <td>Diploma in Children and Young People's Workforce</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
            <input name="qualification" id="29" type="radio" value="29" class="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="sector_quals"></tbody>
</table>
<div class="control-group spacing-top">
    <label for="loan_value" class="control-label required">Amount to Borrow</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-gbp"></i></span>

            <input class="input-small" placeholder="" name="loan_value" type="text" value="" id="loan_value">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my (rubbish) jQuery...

```
function updateAmount() {
    var selectedValue = "";
    var selected = $("input:radio[name='qualification']:checked");
    if (selected.length > 0) {
        selectedValue = selected.val();
        alert('The radio button has been selected and the value is.' + selectedValue);
    }

}

updateAmount();
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You placed the updateAmount() in your document ready?

Comment: will do you want the alert to come? when you click on the radio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling updateAmount too early, bind a click event and have the callback as updateAmount, or the `change` event as roasted mentions, as the event will be triggered only when the actual selection has changed instead of just being clicked on.

```
jQuery(document).on("click",'input:radio[name=qualification]',updateAmount);
```

the `.on` function makes it so current radio buttons and any new radio buttons' click event gets fired

[jQuery `.on` reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[jQuery `click` reference](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

[jQuery `change` reference](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: I'd use the change event instead, anyway +1

Comment: How do you know that he is calling it too early?

Comment: @JonathanRomer He has it being called right after he has declared the function

Comment: @PatrickEvans ah ok, i see what you mean. I thought it was merely an example of the function. But nice insights though, i was thinking on another level.

Comment: He might have been using as an example, but i took he was actually calling it there.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yeh I was calling it straight away! school boy error!

Comment: One last thing, should be: `,'input:radio[name="qualification"]'` or `,'input:radio[name=qualification]'` but looks like OP has already spotted it

Answer (score 2):

Your code is actually fine. The problem is where you are calling `updateAmount()`. If you want this to be called when the user select an option, then call it from within the `change()` event. Like so:

```
$("input:radio[name='qualification']").change(function () {
    updateAmount();
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/thyFT/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Give a class to all `radio buttons`. e.g. radio.

```
$(".radio").change(function(){
    var selected_value = $(this).val();
    alert('The radio button has been selected and the value is ' + selected_value);

});
```